# querying previous row with condition using snowflake window function

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Suppose I have a table as follows:

```sql
create or replace temporary table stock_trade_history (
   type varchar
  ,id varchar
  ,datetime TIMESTAMP_TZ
  ,price float );
insert into stock_trade_history values
    ('trade',1, '2020-01-06 09:00:01.290+09:00', 300), 
    ('trade',1, '2020-01-06 09:00:01.291+09:00', 301), 
    ('trade',1, '2020-01-06 09:00:45.297+09:00', 302),  
    ('trade',2, '2020-01-06 09:00:50.301+09:00', 1000),
    ('trade',1, '2020-01-06 09:01:01.318+09:00', 301),   
    ('trade',2, '2020-01-06 09:01:02.319+09:00', 1001),   
    ('trade',1, '2020-01-06 09:01:03.322+09:00', 300),   
    ('trade',1, '2020-01-06 09:01:04.346+09:00', 299), 
    ('trade',2, '2020-01-06 09:01:31.378+09:00', 999), 
    ('trade',2, '2020-01-06 09:01:40.381+09:00', 1000),  
    ('trade',1, '2020-01-06 09:01:41.382+09:00', 298), 
    ('trade',2, '2020-01-06 09:01:50.426+09:00', 1002);
```

What I want to do is for each row, I want to find the latest price of security id 1 and security id 2.
I've tried using a window function as shown below:

```sql
select 
    *,
    first_value(price) over 
        (partition by id order by datetime desc rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as prev_price
from stock_trade_history order by datetime;
```

However, this keeps giving me the last price values for both security id 1 and security id 2, even with the `rows between` clause. ALso is there way I could add a condition such that if the current row id is 1, then I want the previous row with id 2?

Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT:
Expected output:

```
     |type | datetime           | id 1 price | id 2 price |
    ('trade', '2020-01-06 09:00:01.290+09:00', 300, NULL), 
    ('trade', '2020-01-06 09:00:01.291+09:00', 301, NULL), 
    ('trade', '2020-01-06 09:00:45.297+09:00', 302, NULL),  
    ('trade', '2020-01-06 09:00:50.301+09:00', 302, 1000),
    ('trade', '2020-01-06 09:01:01.318+09:00', 301, 1000),   
    ('trade', '2020-01-06 09:01:02.319+09:00', 301, 1001),   
    ('trade', '2020-01-06 09:01:03.322+09:00', 300, 1001),   
    ('trade', '2020-01-06 09:01:04.346+09:00', 299, 1001), 
    ('trade', '2020-01-06 09:01:31.378+09:00', 299, 999), 
    ('trade', '2020-01-06 09:01:40.381+09:00', 299, 1000),  
    ('trade', '2020-01-06 09:01:41.382+09:00', 298, 1000), 
    ('trade', '2020-01-06 09:01:50.426+09:00', 298, 1002);
```

Comment: Can you show us exactly what output you are expecting?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I added the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case `partition by` won't work, but you can get what you want with `iff()`:

```sql
select * 
    , last_value(iff(id=1, price, null)) ignore nulls
        over (order by datetime rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as prev_price1
    , last_value(iff(id=2, price, null)) ignore nulls
        over (order by datetime rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as prev_price2
from stock_trade_history
```

This gets us the results you were looking for:

[image]